# Precisamos atualizar as perguntas da tag [atualização]

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Primeiro ela precisa de uma boa descrição e recomendação de uso. Quem se habilita?

Depois precisamos verificar se todas as perguntas são do mesmo assunto. Parece que não.

Aí precismos decidir se precisa de uma outra para os demais usos.

Aproveitamos para ver se algumas dessas perguntas nem precisam dessa *tag*. Eu sei que muita gente vai dizer que não precisa. Mas eu vi que a maioria tem a ver com atualização (em mais de um sentido) e ela é útil. Não tenho certeza de todas.

O que você tem a dizer? O que pode fazer para ajudar?

Comment: Sei que você já disse isso, mas ainda penso que é muito ampla, mesmo que utilizada de maneira apropriada ainda sim será superficial. Ainda sim se for manter eu diria que ela só deve ser usada em updates ou upgrades de software, mas não nunca relacionado a coisas como Ajax.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento justamente é isso que quero debater. Onde ela é apropriada. Para mais de um uso certamente não. Se em AJAX precisa de uma *tag* pra isso, aí acho mais questionável, mas pode ser, não tenho experiência suficiente pra cravar que não é útil, aí precisa criar uma mais adequada para isso.Junto eu sei que não pode ficar.

Comment: Olhando agora de outro ponto de vista (afinal precisamos tentar ver todos os lados) realmente parece que pode sim ser benéfico o uso de tags como `configuração`, `atualização`, `concatenação-de-string` e `string` trarão dores de cabeça? Sim, mas ainda sim podem ser úteis, todavia ainda tenho de refletir (eu só não sei se os benefícios são o suficiente para compensar o outro lado)

Comment: Não sei se trarão dores de cabeça. Pelo menos não mais que qualquer outra. Todas *tags* são mal usadas, algumas mais que outras, claro. O que eu estou preocupado é com o mal uso e quero saber o que podemos fazer para resolver isso.

Comment: Sim, por isto disse "inicialmente" que acho esta neste caso é ruim, quero dizer a solução inicialmente seria matar esta tag, mas como citei por ultimo estou revendo essa minha opinião.

Answer (score 4):

*Isto é apenas uma sugestão,*

Serei sincero, não gosto deste tipo de tag, não acho que são benéficas em nenhuma situação e são geralmente superficiais porque mesmo que o assunto seja especifico de um update/upgrade ainda sim o contexto geralmente é em alguma falha e não no update/upgrade em sim.

Quero dizer, se a atualização ou migração de uma tecnologia, ela até parece cair bem, mesmo o que acho bom que deve ser exibido nas tags são as tecnologias usadas e eventualmente a versão nova que deseja migrar.

Supondo que hoje eu use .net padrão e queira migrar para o .net-core, seria algo aproximado de útil, mas apenas aproximado, acho que a pergunta não deve conter a tag atualização.

**Todavia**, se for para usa-la, criar um wiki e etc, então o melhor (menos ruim) caminho seria usa-la somente em dois casos:

1. Update de um software/tecnologia o qual esta falhando por N motivos
2. Update de um código cujo framework usado esta em uma versão nova/diferente

Aonde **não** deve ser usado:

1. Quando a pergunta for off-topic (acho que é óbvio), por exemplo se a pessoa estiver com dificuldade em instalar um sistema do tipo servidor e estiver falhando, na verdade a pergunta deve ser fechada, mas isso é outra história.
2. Referente ao uso de Ajax
3. Atualização do conteúdo de DIVs e Widgets
4. Implementações próprias de sistema de update/upgrade (geralmente o foco não é o update e sim o que falha, por isso listei)

### Wiki

Ainda não vou sugerir um Wiki definitivo, mas o escopo dele tem que ser referente a atualização ou migração de tecnologias existentes.

> Mais uma vez lembra isto tudo é apenas uma opinião e posso estar bem equivocado, sinta-se a vontade para comentar, criticar, negativar (obviamente com o intuito de apontar que discorda de uma ou mais parte da sugestão)

Comment: Mas se é um erro e o fato de ser numa atualização é apenas circunstancial, o problema é ter a *tag* ali, o que não inviabiliza seu uso nos pontos onde a atualização é o foco. A minha visão de uso dela é se você está fazendo um software de atualização (seu item 4, portanto discordo do foco). O fato de estar atualizando algo e deu problema, eu realmente não vejo muita necessidade, provavelmente nem deva ser usada para isso, mas se for, tem que ser bem orientado e temos que ficar de olho o tempo todo.

Comment: Pra mim os 2 motivos citados são ruins :) Acho que dos itens onde não deve ser usada os itens 2 e 3 devem ter outra *tag* ou não ter uma (não sei não tenho experiência pra cravar), o item 1 é inválido mesmo e já falei que discordo completamente do 4. Então precisamos chegar num consenso aqui antes de fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: @bigown só para ter certeza que entendeu, do 1 ao 4 ali é aonde eu discordo, só a primeira lista que tem 1 e 2 que eu *"parcialmente"* concordo ;)

Comment: @bigown só para ver se entendi o seu primeiro comentário, você acha que o uso da tag é favoravel para acaso a pessoa esteja desenvolvendo um sistema proprio de update (codificando)?

Comment: Eu eu discordo mais ainda :) A minha opinião, por isso resolvi por pra debater aqui, é que o melhor é o oposto do que você acha. Você entendeu. Pra mim a *tag* é sobre ela fazer ou usar um software de *update* de aplicação dela. Que é uma ferramenta e/ou biblioteca. Pode ser que precise de uma menos ambígua no lugar desta. AJAX ou manipulação de DOM são coisas diferentes que **talvez** mereçam *tag* própria. Casos provavelmente equivocados: se teve um problema em atualização de software que usa (IDE, servidor de DB, sei lá), porque o fato do problema ser na atualização é algo circunstancial.

Comment: @bigown realmente estou bem dividido em 3 situações a sua e as duas sugestões minhas (a de que a tag não deve existir e a que ela deve existir). Vamos esperar mais opiniões, todavia já é um excelente debate :D

Comment: @bigown então onde se poderia usar a tag? Vendo por estes pontos a tag [tag:SELECT] também poderia ser eliminada, bastava [tag:mysql], por exemplo

Comment: @JorgeB. Dá uma lida nos comentários, o que eu acho. Select já é outra coisa que está esperando pela própria discussão em outra pergunta para ela, a não ser que esteja falando que tem caso que estão usando [tag:atualização] quando querem usar [tag:sql-update]. Embora eu acho pelos comentários que talvez caiba uma discussão maior sobre o conceito das *tags*. Eu percebo que muita gente acha que *tag* é para categorizar coisas coisas, quando na verdade é para marcar com assuntos.

Comment: @bigown foi só um exemplo, eu queria saber em que casos deveríamos usar a tag [tag:select]. A tua opinião, claro.

Comment: @bigown Pode explicar isso de "categorizar coisas" e "marcar com assuntos"? Tem haver com "geral" e "particular"? ex.: "sql" e "sql-update". Ou seja "sql" é uma categoria e "sql-update" é o assunto. Nesse caso só se deverá usar a tag "sql-update"?

Comment: @ramaralNa verdade tudo é assunto, *tag* serve pra isso. Não tem níveis, não tem prioridade. Eu vejo que muita gente usa como algumas coisas mais importantes que outras, mais, algumas coisas não deveriam ser classificadas, e isso é categoria (sub-categoria). Pode colocar 5 assuntos diferentes. Não precisa ficar "miguelando" *tag*. Se cabe uma *tag* pra ajudar classificar, coloquemos ela. Se não ajuda, deixa sem. Todos elas precisam **poder** ser usadas independentemente (não quer dizer que deva). Preciso fazer outro post porque senão vai ficar tendo muitas discussões paralelas.

Comment: @bigown Eu considero que há alturas que a classificação pode e é útil. Tags como c#, java android são quase sempre usadas como classificação e não como assunto.

Comment: @bigown Julgo o que falta não é uma discussão sobre o conceito mas sim um esclarecimento sobre ele.

Comment: Só para resumir, a minha opinião é a mesma do @JorgeB., na maior parte dos casos devemos categorizar as perguntas pelas tecnologias e também acho que é um assunto mais amplo.

Comment: @bigown eu disse a tag [tag:select] mas queria dizer a tag [tag:actualização]. Onde a podemos usar por exemplo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento discordamos bastante então :) Vou fazer um post sobre isso

Comment: @bigown excelente :)

Comment: @JorgeB. A minha opinião é que ou ela não deva ser usada para nada e tenha outras mais específicas, ou ela seja usada quando a pessoa está fazendo ou usando um software/componente de atualização para seu uso.